# Right way to compose navigation links programatically with BootstrapVue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I want to create top navigator from list of routes using [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) library. There are router links in application (computed list in common case) and I need to compose a set of `b-nav-item` elements on the page in the loop. This is vue-component code I've created:

```
<template>
    <b-navbar fixed="top" sticky toggleable="lg" variant="success">
        <b-navbar-brand>App</b-navbar-brand>

        <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
        <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
            <b-navbar-nav>

                <span v-for="item in routes">
                    <b-nav-item :to="item.path">{{item.label}}</b-nav-item>
                </span>

            </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
    </b-navbar>
</template>

<script>
    define(["Vue"], function (Vue) {
            Vue.component('app-navig-top', {
                template: template,
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        routes: [
                            {path: "/home", label: "Home", component_name: "app-home"},
                            {path: "/sign/in", label: "Sign In", component_name: "app-sign-in"},
                            {path: "/sign/out", label: "Sign Out", component_name: "app-sign-out"},
                            {path: "/profile", label: "Profile", component_name: "app-profile"}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Does this approach write for BootstrapVue?

```
<span v-for="item in routes">
    <b-nav-item :to="item.path">{{item.label}}</b-nav-item>
</span>
```

I need to wrap `b-nav-item` with `span` elements but, probably, there is better way to do the same without `span`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `v-for` directly on `<b-nav-item>`, and **don't** forget to specify `key` attribute with unique value.

```
<b-nav-item v-for="item in routes" :key="item.path" :to="item.path">{{ item.label }}</b-nav-item>
```